# JOIN - no matter the order

Tags: mysql

How can i join multiple tables not depending on LEFT or RIGHT join

example:

```
t1 
        id | date
       -----------
       NULL  NULL

t2 
        id | value
       ------------
        1  |  bla

SELECT date,value 
FROM t2 LEFT JOIN t1 
    ON t1.id = t2.id where t2.id = 1
```

-- select is ok

with right join same query return null values ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT `date`, `value` FROM t2 FULL OUTER JOIN t1 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

**Edit:** <strike>That will return all records, even if there is no match on those joining fields.</strike> Sorry, that will give you syntax error. See my edit down below.

If you only want matches, use `inner join`:

```
SELECT `date`, `value` FROM t2 INNER JOIN t1 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

**Edit:** There is no `FULL OUTER JOIN` in MySQL. You will have to simulate it with `UNION` and combine a `LEFT` and `RIGHT` `JOIN`:

```
SELECT `date`, `value` FROM t2 LEFT JOIN t1 ON t1.id = t2.id
UNION
SELECT `date`, `value` FROM t2 RIGHT JOIN t1 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

This will also return your `NULL` values, but they will not match, as `NULL != NULL`

Comment: finally i mixed joins with table, where i am sure  id exists ...
and yes full outer join is not support in mysql http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/05/26/how-to-write-full-outer-join-in-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

You must use FULL OUTER JOIN synstax. In fact Left JOIN returns all results in Left column, whereas right join returns all results in right column. SO with full outer, both are returned.

```
SELECT date,value FROM t2 FULL OUTER JOIN t1 ON t1.id = t2.id where t2.id = 1
```